# AS3 | Changing Z property of an image will remove smoothing

Tags: actionscript-3, bitmap, smoothing, flash-cc

I've an image added on stage while setting smoothing property to true.
Everything is fine until I'm changing the Z property - it will make my image blury as hell, although the smoothing property is equal to true.

Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really. When you apply any 3d transformation to a display object (`z`, `rotationX`, etc) it will be rendered with the 3d projection renderer which, disappointingly, introduces some blurring. If your object is back to `z=0` and you wish to remove the 3d projection completely, set the `transform.matrix`, which removes the `transform.matrix3D` and removes any projection rendering blurring.

For example, the following will make a 3d display object become a 2d display object, removing any 3d projection it had:

```
function remove3D(object:DisplayObject):void {
    object.transform.matrix = new Matrix(object.scaleX, 0, 0, object.scaleY, object.x, object.y);
}
```

Comment: Can you show me an example? How can I set the transform.matrix in order to remove the transform.matrix3D? Can't find it anywhere.

Comment: It's as simple as `object.transform.matrix = new Matrix()`. The `transform.matrix` and `transform.matrix3D` properties are mutually exclusive, if you set one it nulls out the other. I've updated my answer with example that removes 3d properties but preserves 2d properties.